# Discrepancy between classification report and confusion matrix

Tags: matrix, classification

Maybe I'm reading the classification report or the confusion matrix wrong (or both!), but after having trained my classifier and run on it my test set, I get the following report:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.71      0.67      0.69      5086
      1       0.64      0.54      0.59      2244
      2       0.42      0.25      0.31       598
      3       0.65      0.22      0.33       262
      4       0.53      0.42      0.47       266
      5       0.42      0.15      0.22       466
      6       0.35      0.25      0.29       227
      7       0.07      0.05      0.06       127
      8       0.39      0.14      0.21       376
      9       0.35      0.25      0.29       167
     10       0.25      0.14      0.18       229

avg / total   0.61      0.52      0.55     10048
```

Which is good and all, but when I create my confusion matrix:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
[[4288  428   80   16   44   58   33   38   47   21   33]
 [ 855 1218   54    8   12   17   25   15   15   12   13]
 [ 291   72  147    1   12   10   20    2    2   17   24]
 [ 173   21    3   57    1    3    0    1    1    1    1]
 [ 102   20    4    0  113    0    0    6    4    9    8]
 [ 331   40   10    3    7   68    3    0    2    1    1]
 [ 104   30   17    0    1    0   56    2    1   10    6]
 [  85   19    4    2    5    0    2    6    4    0    0]
 [ 270   29    4    1    6    2    2    7   53    1    1]
 [  63   17   11    0    8    3   14    1    1   42    7]
 [ 138   13   19    0    5    2    7    3    6    5   31]]
```

Am I wrong in assuming, that it has predicted 4288 samples of class label `0` out of a total of 5086, which should result in a `recall` value of 84.3% (0.843)? But that's not the number the report spits out. The precision seems wrong as well, unless I'm wrong when I calculate the percentage of correct predictions (4288) with the sum of the rest in column `0`, which results in 0.563, and not 0.71.

What am I misunderstanding?

It might be worth nothing that I use `sklearn`'s [classification_report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) and [confusion_matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) for these.

Comment: There does seem to be something wrong with how those figures are calculated for the 0 class, since the rest seem to have the correct values. I can't think of a reason why though. I haven't been able to reproduce the problem myself.